# Acivate view with moving finger

Tags: android, view

I'm trying to create a field filled with rectangles and if you move your finger the rectangles under it changes color. I've tried it many ways but i did not succeed and i don't have any other ideas. Now my code looks like this, and the problem with it is that the coloring (in the ontouch) only activates when my finger is in the top left corner of the screen and it colors all the rectangles.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
ImageView[][] buttons;
Button b;
TableLayout ButtonContainer; 
RelativeLayout linar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    buttons=new ImageView[5][5];
    linar=new RelativeLayout(this);
    linar.setOnTouchListener(this);

    setPos(0,0,100);
    setContentView(linar);
}

void setPos(float startX, float startY, int size)
{
    float actposX,actposY;
    actposX=startX;
    actposY=startY;
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){

        for (int j=0;j<5;j++){
            buttons[i][j]=new ImageView(this);
            buttons[i][j].setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size));
            buttons[i][j].setX(actposX);
            buttons[i][j].setY(actposY);
            if (j % 2 ==0){
                buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            else
            {   buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);   }
            actposX+=size;
            linar.addView(buttons[i][j]);
        }
        actposY+=size;
        actposX=startX;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    for(int i =0; i< 5; i++)
        {
           for (int j=0; j< 5; j++)
           {
               Rect outRect = new Rect(buttons[i][j].getLeft(), buttons[i][j].getTop(), buttons[i][j].getRight(), buttons[i][j].getBottom());
               if(outRect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
                {
                    buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
           }
        }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Use **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** in your onTouch listener, catch the rectangles and try to fill in it..

Comment: i dont want to separate the motionevents and i dont know how to catch them could you write me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... the getLeft(), getTop().. gives back 0 values so i changed it with this:

```
                   outRect.top=(int) (buttons[i][j].getY());
               outRect.bottom=(int) (buttons[i][j].getY()+buttons[i][j].getLayoutParams().height);
               outRect.left=(int) (buttons[i][j].getX());
               outRect.right=(int) (buttons[i][j].getX()+buttons[i][j].getLayoutParams().height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that,

```
     @Override
                public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final int action = event.getAction();

                    switch (action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        event.getX();
event.getY();

                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent DOWN: x " + selX + ", y " + selY);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        event.getX();
                                event.getY();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent Move: x " + selX + ", y " + selY);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        event.getX();
                                event.getY();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent UP: x " + selX + ", y " + selY);

                        break;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
```

The **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** will detect the pointer movement. You can get the pointer and do your color filling part. Also check logcat for better understanding.. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm maybe wrong, but ... yes this separates the motion events to touch, movement and release but i don't care which motion events activate it my biggest problem is i don't know what to write in the select (int,int) because if i write my select method which is the 2 for cycle I'm right there where i started

Comment: You can use your code in **ACTION_MOVE** case. getX() and getY() will get X and Y coordinate and you can draw with the help of them.

Comment: I get the coordinates with the event.getX() too and I don't need to split the movement cases to get the coordinates. So I have the coordinates to my finger but i cant determinate witch rectangle(ImageView) I'm touching

Comment: How you've drawn your rectangle?? Is it in xml file or you've created it through your logic.. If you've created it logically you can also get it in the touch events,

Comment: the rectangles basically ImageView-s i put a bunch of them next to each other in the setPos() procedure but if i set on touch listener on them.. it only sense the touch not the movement